# Creating a custom axis for bones to rig

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

[image: That's from top view]I want to create a custom axis for a bone to rotate around, which won't be along any one of the axis X, Y or Z. I want to use it for a concept car which uses some body panels to use it as an active air brake. So they'll be operated in an angled way.

Can anyone help...

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use the screen capture functionality of your operating system, rather than taking photos of your monitor. These are hard to read and often harmful to diagnosing issues

Comment: That would take some of my time which I don't seem to have, and I don't want to. However the image was optional so I added it, there's no detail hiding or is this an issue that needs details... Image is just a reference and I know I should have used screenshot, but my problem isn't complicated as now it's marked Duplicate and has an answer already.

Comment: I got my answer BTW, Thanks for the marking. I'll always use screenshot if it's important.

Comment: For this particular case it made little difference, but for shading and rendering issues, or graphical issue it can make the question unanswerable. Thanks for understanding

Comment: Yeah, because it didn't have much importance, that's why I didn't bother to upload a screenshot. I understand it, and I'll know where such are needed. 